# Simple form validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, beginner, validation, ecmascript-6

Used to use Laravel's easy to use form validation class, decided to mimic it in JS. I've been learning JS for 4 days now and decided to write my first piece of real code.

I'm pretty sure its full of bad practices, and a lot of it can be improved. I'm looking for some constructive criticism on what I can do better next time, thanks in advance.

Class:

```
class Validator {
    make(rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    valid() {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty('rules')) {
            return true;
        }

        let errors = [];
        let checkFunction = this.checkRuleForElement; // Storing this here because it doesn't seem to work in its invoked scope.

        Object.keys(rules).forEach(function(key) {
            let formElement = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];

            if (formElement == undefined) {
                return;
            }

            let ruleSet = rules[key].split('|');

            ruleSet.forEach((rule) => {
                let result = checkFunction(rule, formElement)

                if (!result.valid && result.message != undefined) {
                    errors.push(result.message);
                }
            });
        });

        return {
            valid: errors.length == 0,
            errors: errors
        }
    }

    checkRuleForElement(rule, formElement) {
        let isValid = true;
        let error = "no error";

        switch (rule) {
            case "required":
                if (formElement.value.length <= 0) {
                    isValid = false;
                    error = `Form element ${formElement.getAttribute("name")} is required.`;
                }
                break; 
             // todo: alpha => only alpha characters
             // todo: alphanum => Alphanumeric characters
             // todo: num => Numbers only
        }

        return {
            valid: isValid,
            message: error
        };
    }
}
```

Setup (usage):

```
let validator = new Validator();

function checkValidation() {
    validator.make({
        "username": "required",
        "password": "required",
    });

    let result = validator.valid();

    if (!result.valid) {
        alert('Something went wrong.');
        alert('Errors are: ' + result.errors[0]);
    }
    else {
        alert('Validation was a success.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. For better reviews, I suggest you to add some more information what your code does. Not everyone knows Laravel, so an independent description can improve your chances on a good review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must admit this is pretty good code for someone that has just started, I like that you use the more "functional" style Javascript allow you to use . So good job :) But there are some design issues I see with the code.

**1. Factory vs constructor**

Your Validator has a `make` method which takes the rules in, It is basically used as a factory method (A factory is a design pattern if you are not familuar with it). But it has none of the benefits a factory gives you, since it is a instance method.

Having to instantiate a `Validator` object and then being forced to call `make` is cumbersome. Instead I suggest you make the `make` function static and add a constructor

```
class Validator
{
   static make(rules) 
   {
        return new Validator(rules);
   }

   constructor(rules) 
   {
       this.rules = rules;
   }
}
```

**2. Checking class properties**

You don't need to do this check in your `valid` function.

```
if (!this.hasOwnProperty('rules')) {
    return true;
}
```

Since it's practically not possible to not have rules with the proposed factory. I understand why this is here though. You wanted to make sure you can't forget the `make` call after instantiating a `Validator` object. But that's a wrong schematic. If the caller uses your code wrong it should fail, and not say "I don't care, but this is valid"

**3. Naming**

Methods should indicate that they are actions, and properties that they are values.

Your `valid` method sounds a lot like a property, like a value. I would call it `validate` since that is a verb and makes it clear that it does something and not "is" something. And I would rename the property `valid` that your return in your `valid` method to `isValid`

**4. ES6**

EDIT: I noticed to late that you already used an arrow function in your code. Ignore the explanation if you want and just replace the `Object.keys().forEach(callback)` callback with an arrow function. BTW you do not need the parentheses if you only have one parameter.

You can use a arrow function in your `forEach(function)` function. This is a es6 feature and a bit more advanced tho. Using functions is fine but it can solve the issue you have with scoping.

The `function` keyword does create a new scope and therefore changes the meaning of `this`. The arrow function on the other hand behaves exactly like a function but does not change the meaning of `this`

```
validate() {
    let errors = [];

    Object.keys(rules).forEach(key => {
        let formElement = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];

        if (formElement == undefined) {
            return;
        }

        let ruleSet = rules[key].split('|');

        ruleSet.forEach((rule) => {
            let result = this.checkRuleForElement(rule, formElement)

            if (!result.valid && result.message != undefined) {
                errors.push(result.message);
            }
        });
    });

    return {
        isValid: errors.length == 0,
        errors
    }
}
```

Another thing you can leave out is the
`errors: errors` part. You can shorten it to just `errors` since the name of the variable is the same as key of the object

**5. Decouple things**

Currently your "rule running" and "rule definitions" are all in the same class/method (in the switch in `checkRuleForElement`) So if you want to add a new rule you have to modify your Validator class which should only do one thing: Invoke the rules for a element. The rule definitions are a whole separate concern.

You can try to decouple it by using arrays.

A sample implementation may look like this:

`// This is not good code, take it as an "idea" or psuedocode`

```
class Validator
{
   static registeredRules = [];

   static registerRule(name, run)
   {
      Validator.registeredRules.push({ name, run });
   }

   checkRuleForElement(ruleName, formElement)
   {
      var rule = Validator.registeredRule.find(element => element.name === ruleName);
      return rule.run(formElement);
   }
}
```

**6. Abstract things**

A thing you may want to consider is that there may be multiple forms or multiple elements, with your current implementation you are relying on the fact that there are is a unique element foreach "rule". Also you are interacting with the Dom directly which makes things hard to change when that assumption changes.

You could solve this by, for example using Dom elements as an input:

```
Validator.make({
     document.querySelector("#user_input"): "required"
})
```

**Bonus exercises**

You can try to add a more advanced "rule parser" and add parameters for rules.

This could look like this:

```
Validator.make({
  "username": "required|min:5"
})
```

Another thing you could try is, skipping this whole "naming" thing and using just functions

For example

```
const required = element => element != undefined;

// If you do not understand this Syntax, it's basically a function that returns a function.
const min = count => element => element.length > count

Validator.make({
  "username": [required, min(5)]
});
```

This would give you several advantages. For example that your rules can be checked by a static analyzer, If you use strings there is always a chance you mistype something, like use "regired" instead of "required" and not even notice it, with functions on the other hand you will get an error if you use something that is undefined. Also you could reuse rules better.

---

Have fun :)

I wrote this from my mobile so if there are any mistakes let my know. I will most likely add more when I get my hands on a pc!

Answer (score 1):

### Keep it simple

There is an awful lot of arguments being passed and objects being created and returned, on top of  3 exposed functions that are just middle men complicating the core need.

You want to check a rule set and see if it valid, if not then see the errors.

This can all be done via getters for `isValid` and `errors` and a setter for the rule set that also initiates the validation.

You can use `Object.entries` to get the `key` and `value` pairs

```
 function Validator(ruleSet) {
    const errors = [];
    const rules = {
        required(element) {
            if (element.value.length <= 0) {
                errors.push(`${element.getAttribute("name")} is required.`);
            }
        },
         // todo: alpha => only alpha characters
         // todo: alphanum => Alphanumeric characters
         // todo: num => Numbers only

    }
    const API = {
        set rules(ruleSet) { 
            errors.length = 0;
            Object.entries(ruleSet).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                const element = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];
                if (element) {
                    value.forEach(rule => rules[rule] && rules[rule](element));
                }
            });
        },
        get isValid() { return errors.length === 0 },
        get errors() { return [...errors] },
    };
    if(ruleSet) { API.rules = ruleSet };
    return API;
}
```

Instantiating the `Validator` with a rule set and getting the results without the need to force the validation

```
//  Usage 

const validator = Validator({
    username: ["required"],
    password: ["required"],
});
if(!validator.isValid){
    alert('Errors are: \n' + validator.errors.join("\n"));
}
```

### But why create a complex object

You create an object that does not actually contain the information you are after. All you want is the result `{isValid, errors}`

It would be more practical as a basic function

```
function validator(ruleSet) {
    const errors = [];
    const rules = {
        required(element) {
            if (element.value.length <= 0) {
                errors.push(`${element.getAttribute("name")} is required.`);
            }
        },
    }
    Object.entries(ruleSet).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        const element = document.getElementsByName(key)[0];
        if (element) {
           value.forEach(rule => rules[rule] && rules[rule](element));
        }
    });
    return {isValid : errors.length === 0, errors};
}
```

BTW the `split("|")` is a little hacky and limits you rules to be strings. Using arrays to hold the values give more flexibility.

```
const result = validator({
    username: ["required"],
    password: ["required"],
});
if(!result.isValid){
    alert('Errors are: \n' + result.errors.join("\n"));
}
```